# Javascript Check if Image is Selected on Click

Tags: javascript

I'm building a wysiwyg editor and need to check if a user clicks on an image if the selection range contains the image. Is there any way to detect this without adding event handlers to the image?! I'm checking on keyup and mouseup and able to detect if text was selected using Tim Down's getselectedtext() function and would like to just check if the selected range is an image tag or something by checking if the selection contains an el.nodeName.

I can detect the image if the image is fully highlighted using Tim Down's getselectedtext() function but this doesn't return anything if the image is simply clicked(four squares on each corner) rather than highlighted in blue after dragging the mouse across it. Any ideas? Pure JS please.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put one listener on the whole document (only need to attach the listener once), and then check if the event.target (the clicked element) is an image or not.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    console.log('image clicked');
  }
});
```

```html
<div>content</div>
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/34932d3e923ffad9a4a1423e30b1d9fc?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
<div>more content</div>
```